# I forgot the VMs password, can I retrieve it from MongoDB Compass?

Tags: linux, windows, passwords, mongodb

[image: mongodb compass]

Hi,

I have a VM that I forgot the password to. However, I store a database there (which unfortunately is not backed up) and it's no longer responding for some unknown reason. There is an agent that's supposed to take care of stuff like password change requests but it's not working either.

Is it possible to find where MongoDB compass stores it's local saved passwords and can I read it somehow?

Comment: It won’t be plain text and likely won’t be something that can be deciphered without the identity password. Boot the VM in recovery mode and modify the password file for root to something you know. SSH passphrase I assume is how you currently access the account?

Comment: The problem is that the vm is on azure so I don't think I have that kind of access @Ramhound. I use both ssh passphrase and an identity file

Comment: Can’t you just configure the SSH client to use the same identity file?

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure I am quite following, it already requires me to use the same identity file but it also requires me to enter a password. Kinda unnecessary but it's the way it is configured

Comment: So your OpenSSH server isn’t configured for key authentication?